# How to synchronize all methods in class python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python 3 class.

I want to synchronize all methods, only one method can be execute at same time, even works in multi thread.

What is the best way to implement?

```
@synchronized
class Library(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        pass
```

Comment: I found an answer in another place, maybe it can solve your problem：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145796/locking-a-method-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a decorator that locks decorated methods with a given lock.

```
from functools import wraps
from threading import RLock

def synchronized():
    lock = RLock()
    def wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with lock:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper

synchronizer = synchronized()

class Library:
    @synchronizer
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @synchronizer
    def method1(self):
        pass

    @synchronizer
    def method2(self):
        pass
```

However, this requires you to decorate each method. Here I wrote a mixin with `__init_subclass__` that does that automatically.

```
class Synchronized:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        synchronizer = synchronized()
        for name in cls.__dict__:
            attr = getattr(cls, name)
            if callable(attr):
                setattr(cls, name, synchronized(attr))
```

Notice I used a [`RLock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) instead of a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects). A `RLock`, or reentrant lock, allows the lock to be acquired multiple times by the same thread. This allows methods to call one another in the same thread.

### Usage

```
class Library(Synchronized):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        pass
```